# On the possible subgroups of a Sylow subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, say $|G|=p^am$, with $(p,m)=1$, Let $n$ be the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$. Call them $P_1,\dots,P_n$.

Is true that every subgroup of $G$ of order $p^b$ with $b\le a$ must be contained in some $P_i$?

I conjectured this and I think it's true, but I'm not able to prove it.

Any hint will be welcome, thanks!

Comment: This is true and part of Sylow's theorem. If you have done Sylow's theorem then you should know this already.

Comment: And in fact I done it. I'm really tired but I have to finish to study. Thank you again one more time Derek